# Is it possible to block access to files based on their size using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, limit

In particular, I need to deny access to large photos (larger than 1mb). I can't deny access to all images in the folder since the engine (WP) takes smaller, resized, images from the same folder. I thought, if there way to limit access to filetypes, maybe there is the same thing for limiting access based on file size. Is there?

Comment: Does WP add something like `small` to the url? Maybe you could use this to filter out requests for original images as opposed to resized ones.

Comment: WP adds the new resolution to filenames, for example - "original_filename-600x465.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block all original images use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/to/image-folder

RewriteCond $0 !-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.jpg)$ - [F]
```

Comment: If the user names the original image "myImage-600x465.jpg" (even if thats not the real resolution), this will not help. But if the users don't know your RewriteRule, it is realy unlikely that they will try this. So that's better then nothing, but is not 100% secure.

Comment: Does it mean that if the requested file doesn't contain 000x000.jpg at the end of its file name - access is denied? That might work, because original filenames don't (usually) have resolution specified in the name. WP resizes images and adds resolution to smaller copies.
So, if the user opens the url of a small image and then tries to download the original by removing 000x000 from the file name - htaccess won't allow that, right?
Unfortunately, the code placed in the folder with images didn't have any effect.

Comment: You are correct. It forbids all jpg-images except the ones that end with `-000x000.jpg`. As for it not working; try the edit I made above.

Comment: Works! It didn't before only because RewriteEngine wasn't On. Thank you. I will test whether it interferes with uploading of new images and post the result later. Thank you again.

Comment: It doesn't prevent WP to re-compress lage images to smaller versions on upload. It works absolutely fine and I don't think there is a way to download large images without permission. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly, this is not possible. You are not able to check the filesize, because the .htaccess-file is used **before** the picture is loaded.
But it would be possible to create a php-file for this. If you load it like "file.php?urlToImage=myImage.jpg", the script will check the size and if it is small enough it will show the image. Otherwise it could display for example a short warning